# Using media queries how do I make a form that is 600px wide when the screen is greater than or equal to 600px wide (my code included)?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, width, screen

I'm thinking the following...

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.form {
width: 600px}
}
```

Am I correct?

Comment: it should work, did you try it out?

Comment: how maximum the width of the form you want to set? you can put a max-width: or min-width: 600px;. This way your form will be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a media query for this. If you set the width at 600px and a max-width to prevent it exceeding 100% it will work.

```css
form {
   width: 600px;
   max-width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Example Form</legend>
<div>
<label>Name<br /><input type="text" name="name" /></label>
</div>
<div>
<button>Submit</button>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```